# Extract function which is starting new Activity and is used in many different activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've started to learn Xamarin few days ago and now I'm facing a refactoring problem.

Currently I've got multiple screen layout with bottom navigation bar for TABs to switch between screens. Every activity's layout is adding **BottomNavigationBarView** at the bottom and every activity's **.cs** initialize **NavigationItemSelected** inside their OnCreate methods in this way:

```
var bottomNavigationBar = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationBar);

bottomNavigationBar.SelectedItemId = Resource.Id.navigationBarMain; //This id is different for every activity
bottomNavigationBar.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
    switch (e.Item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.navigationBarMain:
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            break;
        case Resource.Id.navigationBarHistory:
            StartActivity(typeof(HistoryActivity));
            break;
        case Resource.Id.navigationBarSettings:
            StartActivity(typeof(SettingsActivity));
            break;
    }
};
```

I would like to extract this piece of code into external function and just call it from every activity only with Resource.Id... parameter.

How can I do that?

Comment: "What would be the best way to do that?" is a opinion-based answer. One person might give you their opinion on the best way, while another might give you another opinion. Have you thought about what the "best" approach would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the inheritance that David Christopher Reynolds suggests here. I would instead consider using composition instead. This way you don't accidentally end up creating this "God"-object of a base class that you start inheriting from everywhere.

Instead, make a strategy:

```
public interface INavigationStrategy
{
    void Navigate(int selectedItem);
}

public class BottomBarNavigationStrategy : INavigationStrategy
{
    private Context _context;

    public BottomBarNavigationStrategy(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Navigate(int selectedItem)
    {
        switch(selectedItem)
        {
            case Resource.Id.navigationBarMain:
                _context.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigationBarHistory:
                _context.StartActivity(typeof(HistoryActivity));
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigationBarSettings:
                _context.StartActivity(typeof(SettingsActivity));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like:

```
var navigationStrategy = new BottomBarNavicationStrategy(this);
bottomNavigationBar.NavigationItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

void OnItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    navigationStrategy.Navigate(this, e.Item.ItemId);
}
```

This way you can easily share code across classes, without inheritance and limiting yourself to using a Base class for everything.

Comment: Thanks for help! That worked for me. I'm new in C#, currently I've got just experience in C++ and I didn't know that it's possible to pass context to another class in this way :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "BaseActivity" which inherits from the Android activity class, and all your activities inherit from. Then you could put a method in the base activity to do what you want. If you set your Activities to inherit from this activity you will be able to easily call it.

Your base activity would look something like this:

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar")]
    public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
    }

protected virtual void SetBottomNavigationBar(int id)
    {
        var bottomNavigationBar = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(id);

        bottomNavigationBar.SelectedItemId = Resource.Id.navigationBarMain; //This id is different for every activity
        bottomNavigationBar.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.navigationBarMain:
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.navigationBarHistory:
                    StartActivity(typeof(HistoryActivity));
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.navigationBarSettings:
                    StartActivity(typeof(SettingsActivity));
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then in your other activities you would do something like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity :BaseActivity 
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //other code

            SetBottomNavigationBar(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationBar);
        }
```

}